# How do I make certain variables global in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, scope, global-variables

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API and an HTML form to add a marker onto a map based on the latitude and longitude coordinates that the user enters into the form. The following is the code of my body in my HTML page:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainForm">
        <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="get">

        Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude">
        Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="results(this.form)">

        </form>
    </div>

    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map">
    <script>
        var latitudeNew;
        var longitudeNew;
        function results (form) {
            latitudeNew = parseFloat(form.latitude.value);
            longitudeNew = parseFloat(form.longitude.value);
            console.log(latitudeNew);
        }
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of the markers
  var UScenter = {lat: 38.1, lng: -96.8};
  var formInput = {lat: latitudeNew, lng: longitudeNew};
  // The map, centered on the U.S.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: UScenter,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true
      });
  map.setOptions({ minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 20 });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Hello</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p>Name</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  // The markers
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: formInput, map: map});
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </div>
  </body>
```

As you can probably already tell by looking at the code, my form calls the function `results` on submit, which defines the variables `latitudeNew` and `longitudeNew`. These variables are later used in the function `initMap` to define the position of the marker with the variable `formInput`. I know that the issue has something to do with the separate global and local variables that I'm creating, but the various solutions that I tried to fix the issue have not worked for me, such as defining the variables as `window.latitude/longitude` and defining the variables outside of the functions.

So my specific question is how do I define the `latitudeNew` and `longitudeNew` variables and where do I place them so that I can get the value of the inputs that the user inserts in the form over to the marker on the Google Map properly?

Comment: `initMap` is called when the API has loaded. `results` is called on user click. In other words `initMap` is called before the other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. the map is initialized by `initMap` which is currently a callback for the API (so it runs when the API finishes loading, before the button can be clicked by the user).  Remove `&callback=initMap` from the API include:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
```

2. The form post is reloading the page, destroying the map, add `return false;` to the onclick function in the `<input type="submit">` tag:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="results(this.form); return false;">
```

**working code snippet:***

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width" 100%;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainForm">
  <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="get">

    Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="38.1"> Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="-96.8">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="results(this.form); return false;">

  </form>
</div>

<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map">
  <script>
    var latitudeNew;
    var longitudeNew;

    function results(form) {
      latitudeNew = parseFloat(form.latitude.value);
      longitudeNew = parseFloat(form.longitude.value);
      console.log(latitudeNew);
      initMap();
    }
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {
      // The location of the markers
      var UScenter = {
        lat: 38.1,
        lng: -96.8
      };
      var formInput = {
        lat: latitudeNew,
        lng: longitudeNew
      };
      var college = "<?php echo $college ?>;"
      // The map, centered on the U.S.
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: UScenter,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true
        });
      map.setOptions({
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 20
      });

      var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">University of California, San Diego</h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p>Devin Provence</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });

      // The markers
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: formInput,
        map: map
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
  </script>
</div>
```